# Flutter retrieving Document data from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to retrieve the data 'name' and 'email' from the current uid's document. However, the data i get is the reference path. Anybody can point me to the right direction? thanks

[Output in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtUS7.png) [Firestore DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdkVs.png) [Flutter codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPgse.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi there**,
The error in your code was that you were not using the method `get()` on the `DocumentReference`. [[Firebase Docs Reference]](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read)
So, below would be the working code for you

```
DocumentSnapshot userDetail = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get();
var name = userDetail.data()['name'];
var email = userDetail.data()['email'];
```

OR

```
var userDetail;
Firestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
   userDetail = doc;
   var name = userDetail.data()['name'];
   var email = userDetail.data()['email'];
});
```

Comment: the console returns 'Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed) '. The name appears as 'Null' but after i refresh the page, the correct name and email appears. Any ideas on fixing this?

Comment: @Roy, I think you did not use `setState()` after retrieving data. Using `setState()`, you can refresh the UI of app after data changes.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are simply making a reference to the document path. You need to make a query for that document instead.

Right now you have:

```
var userDetail = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
```

Change this to:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid)
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot userDetail) {
      if (userDetail.exists) {
        name = userDetail.data()['name'];
        email = userDetai.data()['email'];
      }
    });
```

reference: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read

Comment: The 'name' and 'email' appears as Null.

This is the code from console:
Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)

Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)

Answer (score 0):

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  future: users.doc(USERID).get(),
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("Something went wrong");
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
      return Text("Full Name: ${data['name']} ${data['email']}");
    }

    return Text("loading");
  },
);
```

Take a look at the documentation, you're creating a DocumentReference variable instead of DocumentSnapshot. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage